# INSERT если запись не существует, UPDATE если существует

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Мне нужно создать запись с параметрами:

```
id serial not null, uip varchar(64), ip inet, homedir varchar(128), usname varchar(32)
```

Выйдет примерно что-то такое:

```
INSERT INTO test (
    uip, ip, homedir, usname
) VALUES (
    "deecb935-c79f-4574-a229-077f85068715", "192.168.0.1", "C:/", "Oleg"
);
```

Как мне заинсертить 1 раз и дальше проверять по параметрам, допустим если `ip == 192.168.0.1 или uid = deecb935-c79f-4574-a229-077f85068715 = UPDATE (обновить) запись`?

Comment: Сделать уникальный ключ из связки этих полей и далее использовать ON CONFLICT https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое!!! Можете ответить я  помечу галочкой))

Comment: Можно написать один запрос UPDATE для вариантов добавления/обновления записи и указывать уникальный ключ (из выше предложенного способа). Если такого ключа нет, то добавляется запись. Если есть, то обновляется запись. Итого - один универсальный запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если на `(uip, ip)` есть уникальный ключ, то так:

```
INSERT INTO users (uip, ip, homedir, usname, homedir, usname)
VALUES ("deecb935-c79f-4574-a229-077f85068715", "192.168.0.1", "C:/", "Oleg")
ON CONFLICT (uip, ip) DO UPDATE SET homedir="C:/", usname="Oleg"
;
```